# Is there any way to completely avoid text chat and voice chat in star wars battlefront 2 (2017)

Tags: voice-chat, star-wars-battlefront-2-2017

So, I don't want any voice chat or text chat.  I've heard that text chat can be hidden by pressing **H**, and that voice chat is only used in parties.  but those reddit posts were a year old, so I want to confirm that it is still true.  I also heard that Ewok Hunt doesn't use voice chat, and I'd like to know it that's still true.  thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I Found an option in the Gameplay Options that allows text chat to be disabled.  I'll post a seperate question about the voice chat.

Comment: voice chat is only for parties, text chat can be hidden any time by pressing "H" or using the settings.